# Redirecting old paths on an old domain to a new path on a new domain with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Lets say I have 3 domains:

oldsite.com
anotheroldsite.com
and
newsite.com

I need to redirect specific URLs from the old domains to specific paths on the new domain. Such as:

oldsite.com/potato => www.newsite.com/how-about-a/potato
www.oldsite.com/potato => www.newsite.com/how-about-a/potato
and
anotheroldsite.com/products => www.newsite.com/sub-dir-before/products
www.anotheroldsite.com/products => www.newsite.com/sub-dir-before/products

Finally, I need all non-matching requests to try www.newsite.com/$1

I've spent the better part of the last hour searching for the best way to do this but I can't seem to find any examples that look at an old domain and a new domain with completely different paths.

**Important:** All of the domain name A-records are pointing to the IP for newsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this one URL at a time, depending on what patterns you can get out of how old URLs map to new URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(oldsite\.com|anotheroldsite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^potato$ http://newsite.com/how-about-a/potato [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(oldsite\.com|anotheroldsite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products$ http://newsite.com/sub-dir-before/products [L,R=301]


...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(oldsite\.com|anotheroldsite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

etc.